# Broadcast Receiver for Phone State Listener does not work after few calls

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener

I'm using Phone Call states(`CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK`) and run my BroadcastReceiver class. **it's working 5 or more calls**(incoming/outgoing) **after it stops the service.** I don't know what went wrong here. if I want to run the service again, I want to open the app again. but this is not a broadcast service. and if I call an invalid number which is less than 10 numbers the broadcast services stops

> Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity2"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity> <!-- This part is inside the application -->
    <receiver
        android:name=".CallReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

> MyPhonestatreListener

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Date;

public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    private static int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
    private static Date callStartTime;
    private static boolean isIncoming;
    
    public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String phoneNumber){
        if(lastState == state){
            //No change, debounce extras
            return;
        }
        
        System.out.println("Number inside onCallStateChange : "  + phoneNumber);
        switch(state){
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                isIncoming = true;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                
                Toast.makeText(context, "Incoming Call Ringing " + phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                if(lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                isIncoming = false;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Outgoing Call Started " + phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                //Went to idle-  this is the end of a call.  What type depends on previous state(s)
                if(lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                    //Ring but no pickup-  a miss
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Ringing but no pickup" + phoneNumber + " Call time " + callStartTime +" Date " + new Date() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(isIncoming){
                    
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Incoming " + phoneNumber + " Call time " + callStartTime  , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    
                    Toast.makeText(context, "outgoing " + phoneNumber + " Call time " + callStartTime +" Date " + new Date() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    
                }
            
            break;
        }
        lastState = state;
    }
}
```

> CallReceiver

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Log.w("intent " , intent.getAction().toString());
        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        MyPhoneStateListener customPhoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();
        
        telephony.listen(customPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        String phone_number = bundle.getString("incoming_number");
        
        String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        // String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        int state = 0;
        if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
        }
        else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
        }
        else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
        }
        if (phone_number == null || "".equals(phone_number)) {
            return;
        }
        customPhoneListener.onCallStateChanged(context, state, phone_number);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Phone Number " + phone_number , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

> MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 1;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        checkAndRequestPermissions();
    }
    
    private  boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
        int readPhoneState = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
        int read_call_log = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG);
        List listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
        if (readPhoneState != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
        }
        
        if (read_call_log != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG);
        }
        
        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),
            REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which api do you test?

Comment: API 26 or 27, Android 8.0.0 **Oreo** My real device name- Huwawei y7 2018,

Comment: In my case it was helpful to extract `PhoneStateListener` from a local variable to a class-level one. Don't post it as answer, because not sure how stable the solution is.